# How to read unsigned char from a socket

Tags: c, sockets, unsigned

I have to receive a UDP packet from the socket. In this packet hour, min and sec are sent as UNSIGNED CHAR.  When I receive it in a char[] and put in TextBox for displaying it is not displaying the actual data which are sent, but different values.

```
char buffer[10];
udpSocketRxCDP->readDatagram(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
ui->textEditsec->setText(buffer[2]);
```

Please suggest how I can get the actual data.

Comment: What data is sent?  And what is the full content of `buffer` after calling `readDatagram`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the little given information, you might want to explicitly convert `unsigned char` to `char`. 
Consider that some data *may* get corrupted. However, unless you really need it, you can send the data directly as `signed char`. We can't know whether it's a good choice or not though.

Answer (score 2):

When you read from a socket, you are reading **raw data**.  If you read it into a `char[]` buffer and use it as-is then the data is going to be interpreted as `char`.  So either typecast the data to `unsigned char` when needed:

```
ui->textEditsec->setText( (unsigned char) buffer[2] );
```

Or define a suitable `struct` and typecast to that instead:

```
struct mypkt
{
    unsigned char hour;
    unsigned char minute;
    unsigned char second;
    ...
};

ui->textEditsec->setText( ((mypkt*)buffer)->second );
```

Either way, assuming `setText()` actually expects a `char*` string as input, then use `sprintf()` or similar function to format a string:

```
char str[12];
sprintf(str, "%d", (int) ((mypkt*)buffer)->second);
ui->textEditsec->setText(str);
```